# MasterPage button click event doesn't fire on the first click but on the second click

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

Hi and thanks for your help in advance.
Here's my problem:

- I have a web page that's split into a MasterPage and a Main Page.
- Nothing in either page is setup dynamically (no code-behind) it's all set on the .aspx page.
- On the MasterPage I have a "Save" button.
- On the Main Page I have several textboxes.
- The Main Page textboxes have an event (void SumAll(...)) that's fired when the focus leaves any of these checkboxes.
- On the MasterPage I have a click event wired to the "Save" button.

This is what happends:

- I make a change to any one of the textboxes on the Main Page but the focus doesn't leave this textbox (no SumAll() event fireing right off).
- I then click the "Save" button in the MasterPage.

I expect the MasterPage "Save" button click event to fire but it never does! The Main Page textchange (SumAll()) event fires but the MasterPage click event doesn't.

If I click the MasterPage "Save" button again the MasterPage click event successfully fires but not, of course, the Main Page textchanged event. The same is true for when I just click on the MasterPage "Save" button without making any changes on the Main Page.

Here is a sample of my code.
The Main Page textchanged event:

```
protected void SumTheAmounts(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Decimal lease = 0.00M;
        Decimal securityDeposit = 0.00M;
        Decimal miscellanious = 0.00M;
        Decimal sumTotal = 0.00M;

        Decimal.TryParse(txtMiscellaneousAmount.Text, out miscellanious);
        Decimal.TryParse(txtSecurityDepositAmount.Text, out securityDeposit);
        Decimal.TryParse(txtLeaseAmount.Text, out lease);

        sumTotal = miscellanious + securityDeposit + lease;
        txtAmount.Text = sumTotal.ToString();

        // Set focus to the next textbox
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        switch (tb.ID)
        {
            case "txtLeaseAmount":
                txtSecurityDepositAmount.Focus();
                break;
            case "txtSecurityDepositAmount":
                txtMiscellaneousAmount.Focus();
                break;
            case "txtMiscellaneousAmount":
                txtMiscellaneousAmount.Focus(); // Send back to the same. .
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

And my MasterPage's "Save" button click event:

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save every little thing...
        switch (ContentPageLoaded)
        {
            case "CheckRequest":
                ((CheckRequest)ContentMain.Page).UpdateMe();
                break;
            case "PicturesLoad":
                ((PicturesLoad)ContentMain.Page).UpdateMe();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSave" CssClass="ButtonClass" runat="server">
   <asp:Button ID="btnSave" style="width:160px; font-size:small; position:relative; color:Blue; top: 0px; left: 0px;" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click" CausesValidation="False" /> 
</asp:Panel>
```

PageLoad:

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{ 
   Button saveButton = (Button)Master.FindControl("btnSave"); 
   branchName = (string)Session["BranchName"]; 
   branchLegalData = new Classes.BranchLegalData(); 
   if ((branchName != null) && (branchName.Length > 0)) 
   { 
      FillThisPageData(); 
   } 
} 
else { } 
Master.ContentPageLoaded = "CheckRequest";
```

Any help is very appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the markup for the save button on the masterpage?  Can we also see any code you have in page_load for either page?

Comment: The page_load for the MasterPage only enables buttons on the MasterPage so it's of no consiquence. The Save button is always enabled.

Comment: Please put your code in the original question and not the comments.  I did it for you this time.

Comment: Why do you have this line in your page load: `Button saveButton = (Button)Master.FindControl("btnSave");` and what are you doing with `saveButton`?

Comment: I access the MasterPage save button because (depending on the saved/not saved state) I change the button text from "Save" to "Update"

Comment: I can't chat because I don't have enough "prestege points"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but try setting autopostback="false" for all of your text boxes.  I suspect what might be happening is that you are firing two postbacks when you leave focus on  your textboxes and then click the button in one fell swoop.

This would only happen if you have autopostback set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

setting autopostback="false" on the textboxes worked! 
I think what was happening was that with the autopostback="true" the textbox would fire it's own text-changed event and, for some reason, the MasterPage button-click event wouldn't fire after that?!
Can somebody please tell me why the textbox event fires and not the button event also???

In any case, this problem has been fixed and I appreciate all of the input... You guys ROCK!

Steve

Comment: Glad it worked out.  If you feel like my answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it by clicking on the checkbox in the top left corner of my answer.

The reason you were seeing this behavior is because you can only fire one post back at a time.  You were trying to do two, but the second one wasn't making it.